# My laravel login route leads to a blank page with the same URL

Tags: laravel

My laravel route fails to go to the specified route. I have made a custom authentication page that should lead to `dashboard.blade.php` when a registered user logs in. But it returns a blank page with the same URL for login when a user uses wrong credentials.

**This is my route list:**

[image]

This is my form tag for the login form

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('login.store')}}">
```

**Controller** `store()` **method**:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('employeeID', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        Session::flash('login','login Successful!');
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

**Controller** `index()` **method**:

```
public function index() {
    return view('login');
}
```

**This** `web.php` **source code:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('register');
});

Route::resource('register', 'registerController');
Route::get('/login',function(){

    return view('login');
});

Route::resource('login', 'loginController');
Route::get('/dashboard',function(){

    return view('dashboard');
});
Route::resource('/logout', 'logoutcontroller@logout');
Route::resource('/dashboard', 'dashboardcontroller@index');
```

**DashboardController** source code:

```
public function index() {
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: so your problem is why it's a blank page when the user is NOT logged in and have used wrong credentials?

Comment: Route::resource defines the get method, you have it defined twice therefore. Route login.store isn't defined I assume, you should define the routes individually

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you would define name to a route with Route::resource, by defining the post method: `Route::post('/login', 'loginController@store')->name('login.store');` should do the trick tho.

Comment: In the store method, try returning something after the if statement.